# Make HTML element stays visible once updated from within a JQuery dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I've got a form where the user needs to select some fields.

Upon submitting I would like to do some error checking if the fields are selected, and if not, I would provide a dialog window stating the error message + the possibility to select/update the field from within the dialog window.

I'm able to open the dialog window including the `div` that contains the field selection, but in the general page this `div` will disappear.

How can I make this `div` stays visible during and after the dialog window is open or closed?

See code snippet below or at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua54wgbu/1/)

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {

  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('You forgot something, update below')
    .dialog({
      title: 'check',
      buttons: {
        OK: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

  $dialog.dialog('open');

  $dialog.append($('.classSelector'));


});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

General page to make selection
<div class='classSelector'>
  <p>select car:
    <select>
      <option selected disabled>car type</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the code below after $dialog.dialog('open'):

$dialog.append($('.classSelector').clone());

Using .clone will allow you to copy the whole classSelector div but the original div will still be on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$selecter = $('.classSelector').clone();
$('#submit').click(function () {

    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('You forgot something, update below')
        .dialog({
        title: 'check',
        buttons: {
            OK: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $dialog.dialog('open');
    $selecter.appendTo($dialog);

});
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ua54wgbu/3/)

Comment: The `div` including the field stays visible, but the value of the select element is not updated or stored, see http://jsfiddle.net/ua54wgbu/4/

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I saw that you have wrong html. You didnt close `p` tag ang also why you place `select` in `p`? i you want it from the new line you can place it in `div` or use `br` tag. Second, it seems that you subtract somewhere your select list with button and include it in validation popup. Check this and if so, try to not to subtract your elements

Hope this helps